# How to save a custom software project file

Tags: c#, save

I have built a video editing software.  I would like to add functionality for the end user to save their progress if they have not completed their editing work.  I am a self taught programmer and have no real world experience unfortunately.  Not sure what the best practice is for saving a custom file.  Similar to a word document.  You save the file.  Later you open the file and all of your progress is there.  I need to save the state that the editing process is in.  Not sure how to write that to a file and open my software in that state when the file is clicked on.  Any advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: If your goal is to write data to a file, have you looked up how to write to a file in C#?  What have you tried?  What's stopping you?  Please clarify the specific problem you've encountered.

Comment: ?? You pretty much described the process in the final sentence.  You just need to decide what constitutes the "state" of a project.  You then write code to "serialize" that state into a file, and "deserialize" from the file back to an object.  You might think about moving the project "state" into a single class, but that's not required.

Comment: I can write data to a file.  I guess what I am trying to accomplish is having the ability for the end user to click on that file and it launches my software.  At that point I could consume the data in the file and rebuilt the project to his former state.  How does one open the software by clicking in the file?

Comment: @Jacob: That's a different question entirely, and one that extends more into the host OS than just your application.  But using my favorite search engine to search for *"stack overflow c# associate file type with my program"* appears to yield some helpful results.

Comment: Thank you very much David.  Sorry for rookie questions.  I have studied code intently for 14 years as I love it.  However ; no formal education or work experience has left some gaps.